# Blazor MAUI Hybrid read console log in Production after crash

Tags: c#, browser, blazor, maui, crash-reports

We have a Blazor MAUI Hybrid app that is crashing in production for one of our users but it works great on our test devices. The user gets the "An unhandled exception has occurred".

How can we read the console in order to troubleshoot this and see what the problem is? The app is compiled and distributed via the app stores. The user is running the app on an iPad but it doesn't technically seem to be a way we can ask the user and read the console log for us either.

Comment: If you have physical access to the user's device (or a similar device) and a Mac machine, you can use the [developer tools console](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hybrid/developer-tools?view=aspnetcore-7.0&pivots=windows), or?

Comment: You could find the crash report on device. You could refer to [Locate crash reports and memory logs on the device](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/acquiring-crash-reports-and-diagnostic-logs#Locate-crash-reports-and-memory-logs-on-the-device)

Comment: Also you could try using [Crashes organizer](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev861f46ea8).Once you have a crash report, you may need to add identifiable symbol information to the crash report. You could refer to [Adding identifiable symbol names to a crash report](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/adding-identifiable-symbol-names-to-a-crash-report)

Comment: I don't have access to the physical device where the crash is happening. And the app doesn't crash as per for the OS. It only crashes in the context of Blazor and shows this yellow error bar in the bottom of the screen. If I could read the console somehow it should show the error.

Comment: Can you reproduce, I mean use the same physical device or simulator as the user? And you may also make some try catch statement and write the exception in a file. Then let the user transfer the file to you?